# Interfacing Symfony with Trello by API and cdaguerre/php-trello-api

Tags: php, api, symfony, trello

I am trying to use the [cdaguerre/php-trello-api](https://github.com/cdaguerre/php-trello-api) in order to interface my Symfony app with Trello. I am using key and token.
I have taken the API key from https://trello.com/app-key. I have taken the token by https://trello.com/1/authorize?expiration=never&scope=read,write,account&response_type=token&name=Server%20Token&key=<api_key>

Now, I use the following way for interfacing with Trello API, according to the documentation of the *cdaguerre/php-trello-api* package:
`$client->authenticate('apiKey', 'token', Client::AUTH_URL_CLIENT_ID);`

I have an unauthenticated error. What am I missing, please?

Comment: Can you post the error?

Comment: @KostasKolovos it's simply an unauthorized error

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it by myself. Practically speaking, the problem was due to the GuzzleHttp library, which uses subscribers instead of listeners since version 5.3 in order to adapt headers of HTTP requests.

Now, a package ready for Symfony5 can be cloned from https://github.com/matteocacciola/php-trello-api